# How is the following short sentence allowed to be capitalised?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I saw the following sentence on the opening credits of a film recently: Lady In The Van starring Maggie Smith by Alan Bennett, directed by Nicholas Hytner.

It said on a page by itself:

> **A Mostly True Story**

How is this allowed to be capitalised? I assume of course, they have not made an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headline style has all first letters in a string or sentence capital. So, it's *a style.*

I am not sure which *page* you are talking about though. But generally, taglines just below the title, the headings, the headlines, and stuff the like would have first letter capital. Nothing wrong in that.

However, you may note that this is **optional.**